# Hadoop's default partitioner: HashPartitioner - How it calculates hash-code of a key?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2, hashcode, reducers

I am trying to understand `partitioning` in `MapReduce` and I came to know that Hadoop has a default partitioner known as `HashPartitioner`, and partitioner helps in deciding to which reducer a given key would go to.

## Conceptually, it works like this:

```
hashcode(key) % NumberOfReducers, where `key` is the key in <key,value> pair.
```

## My question is:

How does `HashPartitioner` calculate the hash-code for the key? Does is simply call the hashCode() of the key or does this `HashPartitioner` use some other logic to calculate the hash-code of the key?

Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hadoop partitioner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27595195/hadoop-partitioner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default partitioner simply use `hashcode()` method of key and calculate the partition. This give you an opportunity to implement your `hascode()` to tweak the way the keys are going to be partitioned.

From the [javadoc](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/partition/HashPartitioner.html):

```
public int getPartition(K key,
               V value,
               int numReduceTasks)
Use Object.hashCode() to partition.
```

For the actual code, it simply returns `(key.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numReduceTasks`:

```
 public int More ...getPartition(K key, V value,
                          int numReduceTasks) {
    return (key.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numReduceTasks;
 }
```

**EDIT: Adding detail on custom partitioner**

You can add a different logic for partitioner, which even may not use `hashcode()` at all.

As custom partitioner can be written by extending `Partitioner`

```
public class CustomPartitioner extends Partitioner<Text, Text>
```

One such example, which works on the properties of the custom key object:

```
public static class CustomPartitioner extends Partitioner<Text, Text>{
@Override
public int getPartition(Text key, Text value, int numReduceTasks){
    String emp_dept = key.getDepartment();
    if(numReduceTasks == 0){
        return 0;
    }

    if(key.equals(new Text(“IT”))){
        return 0;
    }else if(key.equals(new Text(“Admin”))){
        return 1 % numReduceTasks;
    }else{
        return 2 % numReduceTasks;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, if we use a Custom key, then the default partitioner would work on that as well, it will simply calculate the hash-code using the default hashCode() of the object (assuming we don't override the hashCode())

Comment: Yes, please make sure that the custom key implements `Writable` interface.

Comment: Ok , so  the default partitioner can work on normal / Primitive Keys as well as on Custom Keys.   This I am now clear. The doubt which I have, is we say we can write a custom partitioner. What we do in custom partitioner? Do we still use the hashCode() or it just depends on the needs? Can you explain a bit on this?

Comment: I don't think that we have a `primitive` keys. Mapper and reducer in java API always need `Writable` (an interface) type; So `int` type is basically `IntWritable` and so on (but they all are object, not primitive). for custom partitioner, I have updated the post.

Comment: When I referred to Primitive , it was Hadoop's "primitives" like IntWritable, Text etc.  However, thanks for adding the details in your answer. I want to check, for Keys we should implement WritableComparable interface, and not Writable; I hope this is correct.

Comment: `WritableComparable` interface is just a subinterface of the `Writable` and `java.lang.Comparable` interfaces. So, its again a `Writable`  :) . Now depending on what exactly you want, you may implement just `Writable` or `WritableComparable`. You may want to check out the scenario for either.

Comment: Thanks for your help in clarifying the doubts , catch you soon in another question :)

Comment: Happy to help :)